# Use return to stop recurisve function in binary tree, but it doesn't stop

Tags: python, binary-tree

Here is my Python code. I want the inorder_Node() function to stop at Node J so I use return before self.right.inorder_Node().

```py
class TreeNode:
    """
    Representing a tree node consisting of
    datum: the datum stored at the node
    left: reference to the left child node
    right: reference to the right child node
    """

    def __init__(self, datum, left, right):
        self.datum = datum
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def inorder_Node(self):
        if (self.left != None):
            self.left.inorder_Node()

        print(self.datum)

        if (self.right != None):
            #print("the current right node is {}".format(self.right.datum))
            return self.right.inorder_Node()

class MyBinaryTree:
    """
    Implementation of a binary tree
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructs an empty tree
        """
        self.rootNode = None

    def print_in_order(self):
        """
        Use in-order traversal and print each tree node's datum
        """
        if (self.rootNode == None):
            return None
        else:
            self.rootNode.inorder_Node()
```

```
# Construct a binary tree
node_d = TreeNode(datum="D", left=None, right=None)
node_i = TreeNode(datum="I", left=None, right=None)
node_j = TreeNode(datum="J", left=None, right=None)
node_k = TreeNode(datum="K", left=None, right=None)
node_l = TreeNode(datum="L", left=None, right=None)
node_m = TreeNode(datum="M", left=None, right=None)
node_e = TreeNode(datum="E", left=node_i, right=node_j)
node_f = TreeNode(datum="F", left=node_k, right=node_l)
node_h = TreeNode(datum="H", left=node_m, right=None)
node_b = TreeNode(datum="B", left=node_d, right=node_e)
node_c = TreeNode(datum="C", left=node_f, right=node_h)
node_a = TreeNode(datum="A", left=node_b, right=node_c)
tree = MyBinaryTree()
tree.rootNode = node_a
tree.print_in_order()
```

Output:

```
D
B
I
E
J
A
K
F
L
C
M
H
```

I thought it would print datum of node J and stop working, but it's still travelling until every node in the tree is explored, printing every datum of every node in the tree. Can you explain the logic of this?
Thank you in advance for clarifying me.

Comment: What in the code is supposed to react specially to J?

Comment: You set `tree.rootNode` to a non-`None` value and there's nothing that would re-assign it to None, so that `return` never executes. Even if `TreeNode.inorder_Node` were to return `None`, there's no assignation of this return to `tree.rootNode`.

Comment: The function would return immediately after doing `self.right.inorder_Node()` anyway, so doing an explicit `return` doesn't really change anything.  (It might affect the returned value, but in this case it's `None` either way.)

Comment: Why do you expect it to stop at `J`?  The inorder_Node() function is currently working exactly as expected and printing the entire tree.  After J, it returns back to the root node A, prints its value as in-order, and then continues to do all the modes right of A.

Comment: Node J's inorder traversal did finish but not the inorder traversal of Node A. Are you looking to implement a search? Because note that the traversal, etc. is different from a search.